# several scriptcam.js on same page, camera won't load/show and take pics

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I am trying to make a demo page using script `cam.js`, I need to have six different "take picture" buttons and six different screens in which the pictures taken will be shown. I have done this all but the camera/webcam won't load, so when I click the buttons there are no pictures taken and no screen from which I can see myself.

Here is what I have written, and yes the `.js` files are correctly linked.

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="scriptcam.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#webcam").scriptcam({
            promptWillShow: showMessage,
            showMicrophoneErrors: false,
            onError: onError,
            cornerRadius: 20,
            cornerColor: 'e3e5e2',
            onWebcamReady: onWebcamReady,
            uploadImage: 'upload.gif',
            onPictureAsBase64: base64_tofield_and_image
        });
    });

    function base64_tofield() {
        $('#formfield').val($.scriptcam.getFrameAsBase64());
    };

    function base64_toimage1() {
        $('#image1').attr("src", "data:image1/png;base64,"+$.scriptcam.getFrameAsBase64());
    }

    function base64_toimage2() {
        $('#image2').attr("src", "data:image2/png;base64,"+$.scriptcam.getFrameAsBase64());
    }

    function base64_toimage3() {
        $('#image3').attr("src", "data:image3/png;base64,"+$.scriptcam.getFrameAsBase64());
    }

    function base64_toimage4() {
        $('#image4').attr("src", "data:image4/png;base64,"+$.scriptcam.getFrameAsBase64());
    }

    function base64_toimage5() {
        $('#image5').attr("src", "data:image5/png;base64,"+$.scriptcam.getFrameAsBase64());
    }

    function base64_toimage6() {
        $('#image6').attr("src", "data:image6/png;base64,"+$.scriptcam.getFrameAsBase64());
    }

    function base64_toimage7() {
        $('#image7').attr("src", "data:image7/png;base64,"+$.scriptcam.getFrameAsBase64());
    };

    function base64_tofield_and_image(b64) {
        $('#formfield').val(b64);
        $('#image1').attr("src", "data:image/png;base64,"+b64);
        $('#image2').attr("src", "data:image/png;base64,"+b64);
        $('#image3').attr("src", "data:image/png;base64,"+b64);
        $('#image4').attr("src", "data:image/png;base64,"+b64);
        $('#image5').attr("src", "data:image/png;base64,"+b64);
        $('#image6').attr("src", "data:image/png;base64,"+b64);
        $('#image7').attr("src", "data:image/png;base64,"+b64);
    };

    function changeCamera() {
        $.scriptcam.changeCamera($('#cameraNames').val());
    }

    function onError(errorId, errorMsg) {
        $("#btn1").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#btn2").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#btn3").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#btn4").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#btn5").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#btn6").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#btn7").attr("disabled", true);
        alert(errorMsg);
    }

    function onWebcamReady(cameraNames, camera, microphoneNames, microphone, volume) {
        $.each(cameraNames, function (index, text) {
            $('#cameraNames').append($('<option></option>').val(index).html(text))
        });
        $('#cameraNames').val(camera);
    }

    function showCurrentVersion() {
        alert($.scriptcam.version());
    };

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width: 330px; float: left;">
        <div id="webcam">
        </div>
        <div style="margin: 5px;">
            <img src="webcamlogo.png" style="vertical-align: text-top">
            <select id="cameraNames" size="1" onchange="changeCamera()" style="width: 245px; font-size: 10px; height: 25px;">
                <option value="0">FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in) (05ac:850b)</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 135px; float: middle;">
        <p>
            <button class="btn btn-small" id="btn1" onclick="base64_toimage1()">
                Snapshot 1</button></p>
        <p>
            <button class="btn btn-small" id="btn2" onclick="base64_toimage2()">
                Snapshot 2</button></p>
        <p>
            <button class="btn btn-small" id="btn3" onclick="base64_toimage3()">
                Snapshot 3</button></p>
        <p>
            <button class="btn btn-small" id="btn4" onclick="base64_toimage4()">
                Snapshot 4</button></p>
        <p>
            <button class="btn btn-small" id="btn5" onclick="base64_toimage5()">
                Snapshot 5</button></p>
        <p>
            <button class="btn btn-small" id="btn6" onclick="base64_toimage6()">
                Snapshot 6</button></p>
        <p>
            <button class="btn btn-small" id="btn7" onclick="base64_toimage7()">
                Snapshot 7</button></p>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 200px; float: left;">
        <p>
            <img id="image_1" style="width: 200px; height: 153px;" /></p>
        <p>
            <img id="image_2" style="width: 200px; height: 153px;" /></p>
        <p>
            <img id="image_3" style="width: 200px; height: 153px;" /></p>
        <p>
            <img id="image_4" style="width: 200px; height: 153px;" /></p>
        <p>
            <img id="image_5" style="width: 200px; height: 153px;" /></p>
        <p>
            <img id="image_6" style="width: 200px; height: 153px;" /></p>
        <p>
            <img id="image_7" style="width: 200px; height: 153px;" /></p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<script language="...>` try `<script type="...">`

Comment: for every single one? for all query? or just the last one?

Comment: it still doesn't work... there is no camera window in which a person can see him/herself... and it is very frustrating. I take the code exactly as it is without changing it from online and download all necessary files and no window shows up!... i even tried putting all files in the main/root folder in case i was making mistakes in  my link/paths.. and still nothing... arrg -.-

Answer (score 0):

I suffered the same problem as you and it cost me 2 hours to solve it.
In my case, I just put all the file of `ScriptCam-masters` (the fold you download from the scriptCam website) to the project root directory. I mean, my project called *WebApplication1*, then all the files should be moved in *"C:\App\vs2010workspace\WebApplication1\WebApplication1"*.

In other words, I use VS2010, so when I create a web application, it will generate several documents. One of the documents is `Site.Master`. All the files in the `ScriptCam-masters` should be moved to the same directory as the `Site.master` file.

Hope it works in your case.